# Google Analytics not recognised in one .m file

Tags: ios, ios7, google-analytics, undeclared-identifier

I've integrated Google Analytics in to my project and it works for all files (maybe 8 other view controllers) except for one file.

Every screen in the viewDidAppear method I call

```
// defaultTracker originally declared in AppDelegate.m
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
       value:@"Screen Name"];

// manual screen tracking
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```

Everyone of them work except for one UITableViewController subclass. My ReportsViewController.m Where I get the following error:

[image: GAI Undeclared Identifier]

This would be symptomatic if I didn't include these lines the corresponding .h file but I obviously do.

```
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

What is likely to be causing this error in this file?

Comment: Try to include #import "GAI.h" in addition to the two imported files of GAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement "This would be symptomatic if I didn't include these lines the corresponding .h file but I obviously do." is inaccurate.

You didn't include GAI.h.